# Where do I get my restored contacts from google?

Tags: contacts

I managed to restore my contacts as per the last 30days but I just can't seem to find where they have been restored to. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to access those data directly on your device (unless it's rooted). There's a system app taking care for them, storing them in a database below `/data` (usually `/data/com.android.providers.contacts`). Apps like your contacts app or the telephony app interact with this via a corresponding service. To be permitted, apps need to declare the `READ_CONTACTS` resp. `WRITE_CONTACTS` permission in their `Manifest` file.